# How can I limit the height of AndroidSlidingUpPanel when expanded

Tags: android, android-sliding, slidingpanelayout

I'm defining the anchor point and it works fine, but I need to control the maximum height of the SlidingUpPanelLayout when expanded.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set the panel's layout_height to whatever you like, and things are done.

Comment: This should be added to AndroidSlidingUpPanel wiki!

Comment: Didn't imagine this could be so easy.. saved lots of time.. i almost gave up and wanted to write my own slider...